# Better functional in/out arguments style in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

This code works fine so far but i don't like the tuples everywhere like this which leads to using _.1 and _2 etc which is less expressive.
I can implement wrapper classes that which have more expressive names.
Is there a better approach?

```
trait DrawingSteps {

  def prompt(savedCommands: List[Command]): IO[(List[Command], Unit)]
  def read(savedCommands: List[Command]): IO[(List[Command], String)]
  def parseAndAppend(in: (List[Command], String)): List[Command]
  def invoke(savedCommands: List[Command]): IO[(List[Command], Unit)]

  def drawingProgram(savedCommands:List[Command] = List()):IO[(List[Command],Unit)] = for {
    t <- prompt(savedCommands)
    rawCommand <- read(t._1)
    commands = parseAndAppend(rawCommand)
    output <- invoke(commands)
  } yield output._1  match {
    case (_:CommandIsQuit)::_  => FP.exit(output._1).run
    case _ => drawingProgram(output._1).run
  }
}
```

Comment: It helps if you post code that compiles.

Comment: If you use [**Better Monadic Fors**](https://github.com/oleg-py/better-monadic-for), I belive you can just `(commands, _) <- prompt(savedCommands)`. Also, why do you have tuples with `Unit`?

Comment: Tuples with Unit because println(...) returns Unit in the IO monad implementation

Comment: But why would you want to return the unit of the println? Just execute the print and return your value.

Comment: compilable code would be too verbose and would not be accepted by SO

Comment: if you see the the rudimentary IO monad I've implemented myself it may make more sense, but i feel this is drifting away slightly from the question

Comment: @jakstack oh, you made your own `IO`, ok cool for you. Returning to the problem it is quite simple, you can use pattern matching to name the components of the tuple... however, you either have to: 1. Implement your own `withFilter`. 2. Write plain `map/flatMap` calls instead of using `for`. 3. use **Better Monadic Fors** as I suggested in my very first comment.

Comment: can you please answer the question with basic sudo code so that i can accept your answer thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use pattern matching to deconstruct case classes/tuples and give meaningful names instead of using tuple elements (`_1`). Here is an example:

```
trait DrawingSteps {

  def prompt(savedCommands: List[Command]): IO[(List[Command], Unit)]
  def read(savedCommands: List[Command]): IO[(List[Command], String)]
  def parseAndAppend(in: (List[Command], String)): List[Command]
  def invoke(savedCommands: List[Command]): IO[(List[Command], Unit)]

  def drawingProgram(savedCommands:List[Command] = List()):IO[(List[Command],Unit)] = for {
    (inCmd, _) <- prompt(savedCommands)
    rawCommand <- read(inCmd)
    commands = parseAndAppend(rawCommand)
    (outCmd, _) <- invoke(commands)
  } yield outCmd match {
    case (_:CommandIsQuit)::_  => FP.exit(outCmd).run
    case _ => drawingProgram(outCmd).run
  }
}
```

I guess you could replace tuples with HLists if you find yourself having lots of tuples with arity greater than 2. Looking at your code you have lots of repetitive return types like `IO[(List[Command], Unit)]` which can be declared with type alias or could benefit from being refactored into a case class for even better naming.